# Register minimal API IEndpointRouteBuilder with Scrutor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, minimal-apis, scrutor

I have created an Interface.

```cs
public interface IEndpoint
{
    RouteGroupBuilder MapRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder rotues);
}
```

And it's implementation like this.

```cs
public class TodoApi : IEndpoint
{
    public RouteGroupBuilder MapRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder rotues)
    {
        var group = rotues.MapGroup("/todo");
        group.MapGet("/", () => "Hello");
        return group;
    }
}
```

And I am able to load the classes with Scrutor like this.

```cs
var enpointServices = new ServiceCollection();
enpointServices.Scan(scan =>
    scan.FromAssemblyOf<IEndpoint>()
    .AddClasses(classes => classes.AssignableTo<IEndpoint>())
    .AsImplementedInterfaces()
    );
```

Now how do I register the endpoints in WebApplication app `Program.cs`.

```cs
var app = builder.Build();
foreach (var item in enpointServices)
{
    if (item.ImplementationInstance is IEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        // What to do now?
    }
}
```

Thanks

I have tried to use `app.MapGroup` but it takes two parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build-in DI provider supports resolving enumerable of registered types, so just build the service provider from collection and resolve enumerable of the `IEndpoint`:

```cs
var serviceProvider = enpointServices.BuildServiceProvider();
foreach (var item in serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<IEndpoint>>())
{
    item.MapRoutes(app);
}
```